# Why does this MySQLI prepared statement allow SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement, code-injection

As I was teaching students how to prevent SQL injection today, I was mildly embarrassed. In professional projects I've used prepared statements / parameterized queries as one layer of prevention against SQL injection (although I've never used mySQL professionally). In theory, I thought SQL injection was impossible when using a prepared statement.

But then this worked...

```
$Search = $_GET['s'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $Search);
$stmt->execute();
$Results = $stmt->get_result();
```

If I pass the parameter "?s=1 OR 1=1" then I can get a full listing of all products. I still can't insert another query at the end, but I am confused about why this type of basic SQL injection is possible in mysql/php. I assumed that the parameter "1 OR 1=1" would be rejected because it isn't numeric (obviously I could run that numeric check ...).

Can anyone explain why this works, and what I don't understand about prepared statements in php/mysql?

My school computer has an out-of-the-box Zend WAMP installation btw.

EDIT: This is the string value that is causing my confusion:

```
$Search = "1 OR 1=1";
```

Comment: Two things: 1 - What is the type of the column: int or varchar?; 2 - what happens if you specify the type in the binparam statement: `$stmt->bindParam(':id',$Search, PDO::PARAM_INT)`. That should cast the variable to an integer

Comment: @stUrb That's PDO. This is not. Also, the type of the column should be irrelevant.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the case using a specific *fixed value* (e.g. string) for `$Search` and update the code?

Comment: (Also, include a sample of the rows returned)

Comment: Whoops indeed its mysqli instead of PDO. My bad.

Comment: This is my own fault. Thank you for your help. You are correct. I just had a typo in my page (as happens commonly when writing scripts on the fly in class).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's ok, no any kind of SQL injection here, you do not see list of all products (at least code you provided cannot show it)

you do not need to cast to int, lets go deeper what bind_param actually do:

it has string "i" which means 1 `integer` argument

you're passing value from $_GET which is `string`

bind_param tries to convert String to int, so check this php code:

```
echo intval('a', 10); // output 0
echo intval('1a', 10); // output 1
echo intval('12a', 10); // output 12
echo intval('b1', 10); // output 0
echo intval('1 or 1=1', 10); // output 1
echo intval("?s=1 OR 1=1", 10); // output 0
```

so, you output products with id=1, maybe you have some of them?

Comment: I thought OP meant the parameter was `1 OR 1=1`, as in `http://myinsecuresite.com/test.php?s=1 OR 1=1`

Comment: Seems like as good an explanation as any: might not be a distinct ID.

Comment: @EdCottrell yes, that is what OP meant, and `1 or 1=1` converts just to `1`

Comment: @IlyaBursov: exactly.  I see you've tweaked your answer, though, so that addresses my question.

Comment: Yes, in my example it converted "2 OR 1=1" to 2

Comment: @EdCottrell yes, basically say: casting to int tries to get as maximum number from the string as possible, if first symbol is not digit - then return 0

Comment: Haha, so much for loosely typed programming

Comment: You are correct. I had a typo in my quickly-created in-class script. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce your case, but couldn't.

### Database

```
CREATE TABLE `Document` (
  `DataID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DataID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (1,'BI8392');
INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (2,'HE8492');
INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (3,'HE8493');
INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (4,'HE8490');
```

### Code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$passwd = "";
$user = "user";
$bdd = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $passwd, $bdd);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

if (!$conn) {
   printf('Error connecting to mysql. Error code: ', mysqli_connect_error());
   exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Document WHERE DataID = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

    $param = "2 OR 1=1";
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($results);

    var_dump($data);
}
```

### Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    string(6) "HE8492"
  }
}
```

Seems, that 1=1 condition was ignored.

Comment: @PeeHaa Sorry about 2 posts - browser glitch

Comment: You are correct. I had a typo in my quickly-created in-class script. Thank you.