# SQL injection and prepared statement, when does it get overkill?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I've read alot about sql injection and i've been using mysqli prepared statement for over a year now. The closer i got to my question was this one [Why does this MySQLI prepared statement allow SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846830/why-does-this-mysqli-prepared-statement-allow-sql-injection)

Now, i want to create a function to run a query based on search criteria from the user. I'm using this so i could used lots of different criteria.

Here a simplified example so you can wrap your head around my question:
Let says we have two tables, One with tires and one with Wheels.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wheels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `brand` (`brand`),
  KEY `size` (`size`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tires` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `brand` (`brand`),
  KEY `size` (`size`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
);
```

Now we have a form to let the user make his search

```
<form method='post' ...>
  Looking for : <select name='item'>
    <option value='tires'>Tires</option>
    <option value='wheels'>Wheels</option>
  </select>
  Search by : <select name='type'>
    <option value='size'>Size</option>
    <option value='price'>Maximum price</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' name='criteria' />
</form>
```

Now the php to handle the request would look something like this:

```
$item=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'item',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$type=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'type',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$criteria=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'criteria',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

function build_query($item,$type,$criteria){
  switch($item){
    case 'tires': $table='tires'; break;
    case 'wheels': $table='wheels'; break;
    defaults: /*error handling : bad search criteria*/ break;
  }
  switch($type){
    case 'size': $field='size'; $operator='='; break;
    case 'price': $field='price'; $operator='<='; break;
    defaults: /*error handling : bad search criteria*/ break;
  }
  $value=intval($criteria);

  $sql= ....

  //Do the rest of sqli magic here and return the results.

}
```

PLEASE TAKE NOTE that only the $criteria (that become $value) is not 'hard coded' and sent to the DB from the search form. 
**SO THE QUESTION WOULD BE :** If the $table, $field and $operator variable are from my php internal code, is it necessary to bind them as well?

In other words:

Is this overkill?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ???"; 
$stmt->bind_param('sssi',$table,$field,$operator,$value);
```

AND / OR Is this sufficient?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$field.$operator."?";
$stmt->bind_param('i',$value);
```

*As mentioned before, this is an simplified example so you have a better understanding of the question.*

Comment: You can't bind table names, column names, or really anything that's not a column value. However, you do seem to have the requisite amount of paranoia to disallow unvalidated input from making it into your queries.

Comment: @Sammitch  Agree.  `$value=intval($criteria);` and using `filter_input()` and then the switch statement appears to be excessive.

Comment: I know there are several available PHP based dynamic query generators that are specifically designed to do so.  I've heard some good things about them, but have only briefly investigated using them.  I will search back to see if I could find the one I was considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are going to far using PDO.  PDO is only used for parameters, and not for tables or operators.  Use your second query.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php does not indicate that tables and operators are allowed, and I recall testing this a while back, and found that they are not.

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.
>
> Most parameters are input parameters, that is, parameters that are
>   used in a read-only fashion to build up the query. Some drivers
>   support the invocation of stored procedures that return data as output
>   parameters, and some also as input/output parameters that both send in
>   data and are updated to receive it.

Comment: This is true but with a caveat: If you're developing a library for general consumption, you should [make sure that table names are escaped](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb/blob/8cceada0079eeab486c74769ad34482a03af0073/src/EasyDB.php#L313-L340) properly, depending on the database driver you are using.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - The OP even did a whitelisting, this is probably the safest way to build queries with table/field names.

Comment: Yes, a whitelist is the safest way to do it. I was mentioning a footnote rather than a contradiction. That's why I specified "a library for general consumption" and linked to an example. I apologize if I failed to make my intention clearer.

Comment: As a remark, This is mysqli and not PDO. But thanks for you answer user1032531